# grep for second word from the surrounding lines of first word

Tags: shell, awk

I have a file like this:

> ```
> ABC1  OBJECT-TYPE
> ...
> ...
> KEY { XYZ1 }
> ...
> ...
>
> ABC2  OBJECT-TYPE
> ...
> ...
> ABC3  OBJECT-TYPE
> ...
> ...
> KEY { XYZ3 }
> ...
> ...
> ```

My first search word is KEY (as its occurs less in a file) and second search word is OBJECT-TYPE.  OBJECT-TYPE can occur few lines (may be 5 or 10) above the line with KEY. If a KEY is found in a file, I need output that has the key-value and corresponding object-type-value.

Exactly like:

> ABC1 KEY1
>
> ABC2 KEY2

Comment: please replace the "something like" part of your question with an "exactly like" part, to make your question more precise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want all keys for all objects, and keys are listed below objects, this is how you might do it:

```
awk '/OBJECT-TYPE/ { obj= $1 } /KEY { .* }/ { print obj, $3 }' file.txt
```

output:

```
ABC1 XYZ1
ABC3 XYZ3
```

In case you only want the keys of the first object in each tree of objects, where object trees are separated by an empty line you should try this:

```
awk 'BEGIN { nl=1 } /^$/ { nl=1 }  /OBJECT-TYPE/ && nl { obj= $1; nl=0; } /KEY { .* }/ { print obj, $3 }' file.txt
```

output:

```
ABC1 XYZ1
ABC2 XYZ3
```

Comment: Thanks this solution is also helps. I needed all keys so going with option 1.

Answer (score 0):

The following may be close. It works for the given input, but it makes assumptions that I do not know are true. For example, it assumes that the curly brackets have spaces between them and the key value.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

/OBJECT-TYPE/ {
  for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
     if( $i ~ /OBJECT-TYPE/ )
        key = $(i-1);
  }
}

/KEY +\{.*\}/ {
   for(i=1; i < NF; i++) {
      if ( $i == "KEY" ) {
         print key, $(i+2);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, OBJECT-TYPE and KEY are on different lines in the input file. I had not give block-quote in my first couple of edits.

Comment: @ericsmith: I might not be understanding, but the answer still works for that input.  It doesn't rely on them being on the same line.

Comment: @ericsmith: If you think this answers your question, please modify your question so it matches the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what you're really trying to do.

```
awk '/OBJECT-TYPE/ {a[$1]=$1} /KEY/ { print a["ABC" substr($3,length($3))], $1; split("",a) }'
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to iterate through the file **backwards**, find the KEY and the all the Object-Types *following* the key.

```
tac filename | awk '/KEY/ {key = $3} /OBJECT-TYPE/ {print $1, key}'
```

Given your example above, this outputs

```
ABC3 XYZ3
ABC2 XYZ3
ABC1 XYZ1
```

If you need the output to appear in the same order as the original file, add `|tac` to the pipeline.

Comment: but ABC2 XYZ3 should not be there in the output. Good to know about tac command.

Comment: @ericsmith, your requirements weren't that clear. Glad you found something that works though.